# App force closes with the use of runnable

Tags: java, android

I have to do a big task while a button click in my android app so i am using runnable to do background work. My works fine without the use of runnable but big task freezes it for a while. After the use of runnable my app is getting crashed on button click.
Here is my code for button onClick function:

```
 public void doSearch(View v)
{
    EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchText);
    String query = et1.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Searching Lyrics for "+query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    final String query1 = query.replaceAll(" ", "+");
    Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://example.com/search.php?q="+query1);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                String line = null;
                int count=0,counter=0, disCount=0;
                String[] name = new String[20];
                String[] link = new String[20];
                String[] dis = new String[20];
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && counter<20){
                    if(count == 1){
                        if(line.contains("href=\"")){
                            line = line.substring(line.indexOf('=')+2);
                            link[counter] = line.substring(0, line.indexOf('"'));
                            line = line.substring(line.indexOf('"')+2);
                            name[counter] = line.substring(0, line.indexOf('<'));
                        }
                        if(disCount==1){
                            if(line.contains("<b>")){
                                line = line.replaceAll("<b>", "");
                            }
                            if(line.contains("</b>")){
                                line = line.replaceAll("</b>", "");
                            }
                            dis[counter] = line+"...";
                            counter++;
                            disCount=0;
                        }
                    }
                    if(line.equals("<div class=\"sen\">")){
                        count = 1;
                    }
                    if(line.equals("<div>")){
                        disCount=1;
                    }
                    if(line.equals("</div>")){
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }
                is.close();
line 82:            searchResult(name, link, dis);
            }catch(IOException e){} catch(IllegalStateException e){}
        }
    };
    Thread myThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
    myThread.start();
}

public void searchResult(String[] name, String[] link, String[] dis)
{
   line 91:     setContentView(R.layout.results);
    nameTemp = name;
    linkTemp = link;
    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        if(name[i]==null) break;
        if(name[0]==null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! No results matched your query. \n Try again! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        RowItem item = new RowItem(name[i], dis[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Loading Lyrics for "+nameTemp[position]+"!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowLyricsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("link", linkTemp[position]);
   startActivity(i); 
}
```

Here is my logcat:

```
 I/ActivityManager(15444): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10100000 cmp=com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics/.MainActivity }
 V/ActivityThread(28108): Reporting idle of ActivityRecord{4a2ccbe0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4a2cc658 {com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics/com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics.MainActivity}} finished=false
 I/WindowManager(15444): Delivering pointer 0 > Window{4a5e2508 com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics/com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics.MainActivity paused=false}
 I/WindowManager(15444): Delivering pointer 1 > Window{4a5e2508 com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics/com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics.MainActivity paused=false}
 I/WindowManager(15444): Dispatching key to Window{4a5e2508 com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics/com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics.MainActivity paused=false}
 I/WindowManager(15444): Dispatching key to Window{4a5e2508 com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics/com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics.MainActivity paused=false}
 I/WindowManager(15444): Delivering pointer 0 > Window{4a5e2508 com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics/com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics.MainActivity paused=false}
 I/WindowManager(15444): Delivering pointer 1 > Window{4a5e2508 com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics/com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics.MainActivity paused=false}
 E/AndroidRuntime(28108):   at com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics.MainActivity.searchResult(MainActivity.java:92)
 E/AndroidRuntime(28108):   at com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics.MainActivity$100000000.run(MainActivity.java:82)
 W/ActivityManager(15444):   Force finishing activity com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics/.MainActivity
 I/ActivityManager(15444): Process com.BoxscapeInc.SongLyrics (pid 28108) has died.
```

Somebody please help me with this error.
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You have 2 catch statement who does nothing!! They might be hiding the error you are getting!

Comment: you are calling `searchResult` from the worker thread. You can manipulate the UI only from the main/UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android you can modify UI components only from main thread. You are accessing components in `searchResult` method called from other thread.

You can do it that way:

```
et1.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        searchResult(...);
    }
});
```

It will force you to make some variables final, so you can use them in anonymous object. It is OK. See [post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method.

Personally I would recommend you using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class instead of raw Java thread. It composes running one method in background thread and running another method in main thread.

Comment: @ashu updated answer, see `AsyncTask` link, it has a clear example.

Comment: I think you can access UI components from other threads, but you can't modify them. For example, you can call the `getText()` from an `EditText`, but you can't call `setText(CharSequence)`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing network calls like you have done , I suggest you use this library

you can have a look at here

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

your code will become very very less , instead of declaring so may asynctask seperately writing bulk of code , you can just use 4 lines of code

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(String response) {
    System.out.println(response);
   }
});
```

It is very efficient in getting the response very quickly in 2 secs.
you don't need to use buffer reader or stuff to format the response. You can directly use the response recieved in string "response" of onSucces method.

I hope this will help you out. :)

Comment: Hence no need to use asynctask classes or runnable or thread bullshit .

Comment: @ Udit Kapahi The library you suggest could very well solve the problem, but how about explaining the OP that he cannot touch the UI outside of the UI/main thread and show use some kind of Handler mechanism or a AsyncTask to manipulate UI on the main thread.

Comment: I didn't get what are you trying to say buddy.

Comment: @ Varun :See if you want to update the UI while such network calls , you can simply do all that UI task in the onSuccess() method while using the string response. for example: --- tv.setText(response); inside the onSuccess method will immidiately upate the textview once the JSON or XML stuff is recieved. Its up to you how you want to parse the response and display data in your app.

Comment: I hope this explains your question.